# How to handle SQL queries to a database with a propability of 100+ combinations?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I have 9 fields to my user interface , each one is representing a column in my database table.
So the problem is that i need to cover all the possible combinations of the 9 fields and send specific queries to the database.
Example :
If the user puts 2 fields , i return all the items from the DB that matches to the combination of these 2 items.
If the user puts 3 fields , i return all the items from the DB that matches to the combination of these 3 items.
Its obvious that the combinations are 100+ if you calculate them.
Using JAVA and MySQL with JDBC driver, the Prepared Statement is provided which secures SQL Injection.
But this way , i should make 100+ functions just to cover all the combinations and the code will be repititive .

HOW I SOLVE IT :
I created a Query Generator which takes the input the user entered and creates an SQL QUERY as a String.
Then i pass it to the DB using the Statement Class . This way i cover all the possible combinations but i have to craft SQL Injection protection from zero by my own and generally it is a custom solution to a problem that i m sure its already solved.

If there is an official way to do this please let me know!

Comment: I do the same thing you described as your current solution: building an SQL query as a string with application logic to append search terms to the query based on inputs, is how I solved it. Just be careful to allowlist the columns. Do not use the input directly in your SQL query, or that will be SQL injection.

Comment: Is that the way companies deal with this ?

Comment: It is the more popular solution everywhere I've worked. The solution in Akina's answer is clever, but I have never seen anyone use it in a real company.

Comment: Also i thought of making a generator which generates queries for the Prepared Statement Class. That way i can take advantage of the SQL Injection safety the class provides at the cost of developing my QueryGenerator more.
In any case , i never have worked in a company and i m glad i found the solution by myself :D haha

Comment: Yes, do use query parameters instead of interpolating variables into the SQL query. Those who don't end up explaining why their site got hacked because of their code!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table.*
FROM table
JOIN ( SELECT @column1 AS column1
            , @column2 AS column2
                 ......
            , @column9 AS column9 
       ) AS criteria ON ( table.column1 = criteria.column1 OR criteria.column1 IS NULL)
                    AND ( table.column2 = criteria.column2 OR criteria.column2 IS NULL)
                                      ..........
                    AND ( table.column9 = criteria.column1 OR criteria.column9 IS NULL)
```

If the user have entered the value for some column then you provide entered criteria  into the query else you provide NULL (`command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@columnX", (object)value ?? DBNull.Value)`).

Comment: Thank you but  i dont need to JOIN tables.
I have one table and just need to make the search easy and not too complicated to code it.
If you have the time can you please explain how the code you provided works with JDBC?

Answer (score 0):

You have basically two possibilities to approach this problem.

The first one uses one statement with the **OR conditions handling the missing criteria**.

The second approach uses **dynamically generated statement containing only the predicates with given values**.

The drawback of the first solution is that you get *one* statement, i.e. *one execution plan* that handles all inputs.

The second solution allow to select the proper execution plan based on the input. The drawback is that you land with a *different number* of bind variables, which makes it technically difficult to handle.

Here comes in the idea popularized for years by [Tom Kyte](https://asktom.oracle.com/Misc/oramag/on-popularity-and-natural-selection.html)

You generate the predicate for each selection, but dependent on if the value is given or not:

```
column = :bind_variable -- if the value is passed

(1=1 or :bind_variable is NULL) – if no value is NOT passed
```

The shortcut logic eliminates the predicates with no values but you get the complete number of bind variables in the prepared statement.

**Example with three column all passed**

```
where
col1 = :1 and
col2 = :2 and
col3 = :3
```

**Example with one input**

```
where
col1 = :1 and
(1=1 or :2 is NULL) and
(1=1 or :3 is NULL)
```

**Example with no input**

```
where
(1=1 or :1 is NULL) and
(1=1 or :2 is NULL) and
(1=1 or :3 is NULL)
```

Here the Oracle execution plan for the second example showing that only the `col1` predicate is evaluated, all other are discarded. Similar is valid for PostgreSQL, I did not test MySQL.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |          |     1 |    18 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TEST     |     1 |    18 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | COL1_IDX |     1 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - access("COL1"=TO_NUMBER(:1))
```

For the third query (no criteria) you end with a `full table scan`

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |  1000K|    17M|   896   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TEST |  1000K|    17M|   896   (1)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

*So if the cardinality of the result is highly dependent on the selection this approach is more suitable that the one size fits all `OR` predicate solution*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
I actually implemented the second solution via Java code. Is it optimal to do the implementation of solution in the database or you can choose to do it in your server for example?

Comment: Both options (DB service or client generated SQL Query) are possible. What is better (optimal) dependes only on the developers orientation (DB centered vs. client centered;) @ΝίκοςΑνδρεάδης

Comment: I dont have the reputation to upvote yet :P